# SQL count 2 equal columns and select other columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, count

I have a two separate tables, one with vacancies, and one with applications to those vacancies. I want to select a new table which selects from the vacancies table with a number of other columns from that table, and another column that calculates how many applications there are for those vacancies. So my vacancy table looks like this:

```
ID  Active  StartDate   JobID   JobTypeID   HoursPerWeek
1   1       2017-02-28  2       CE          0
2   1       2017-02-15  4       CE          40
3   1       2017-02-14  1       CE          40
4   1       2017-02-28  1       CE          48
```

My applications table looks like this:

```
ID  VacancyID   Forename    Surname     EmailAddress        TelephoneNumber
1   1           John        Smith       jsmith@gmail.com    447777777777
2   2           John        Smith       jsmith@gmail.com    447748772641
3   2           John        Smith       jsmith@gmail.com    447777777777
4   2           John        Smith       jsmith@gmail.com    447700123456
5   4           John        Smith       jsmith@gmail.com    447400123569
6   4           John        Smith       jsmith@gmail.com    447400126547
7   4           John        Smith       jsmith@gmail.com    447555123654
```

I want a table that looks like this:

```
ID  Active  StartDate   JobID   HoursPerWeek    NumberOfApplicants
1   1       2017-02-28  2       0               1
2   1       2017-02-15  4       40              3
3   1       2017-02-14  1       40              0
4   1       2017-02-28  1       48              3
```

How can I select that table using joins and count the number of applicants where the VacancyID is equal to the ID of the first vacancy table? I have tried:

```
select Vacancy.ID, VacancyID, count(*) as NumberOfApplications from VacancyApplication
join Vacancy on Vacancy.ID=VacancyID
group by VacancyID, Vacancy.ID
```

This obviously doesn't select all the other columns and it also does not select ID 3 because there are 0 applications for that - I want ID 3 to be there with a value of 0 as well as all the other columns. How do I do this? I've tried various forms of grouping and selecting but I'm quite new to SQL so I'm not really sure how this can be done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `RIGHT JOIN` instead of `INNER JOIN` and count the `vacancyid` column from `vacancyapplication` table. For the non matching records you will get count as `0`

```
SELECT v.id, v.Active, v.StartDate, v.JobID, v.HoursPerWeek
       Count(va.vacancyid) AS NumberOfApplications 
FROM   vacancyapplication va 
       RIGHT JOIN vacancy v 
               ON v.id = va.vacancyid 
GROUP  BY v.id, v.Active, v.StartDate, v.JobID, v.HoursPerWeek
```

Start using `Alias` names, it makes the query more readable

Comment: Unlike right joins, that makes the query more confusing... :-)

Comment: @ZoharPeled Just don't want to change OP's join order ;) but what you said is true..

Answer (score 0):

Use `left join` and table aliases:

```
select v.ID, count(va.VacancyID) as NumberOfApplications
from Vacancy v join
     VacancyApplication va
     on v.ID = va.VacancyID
group by v.ID;
```

You seem to want all the columns.  You could include them in the `group by`.  However, a correlated subquery or `outer apply` is simpler:

```
select v.*, va.cnt
from vacancy v outer apply
     (select count(*) as cnt
      from VacancyApplication va
      where v.ID = va.VacancyID
     ) va;
```

This is probably more efficient anyway, especially if you have an index on `VacancyApplication(VacancyID)`.

Comment: Where is va.cnt coming from?

Comment: @HaydenPerry I'm guessing Gordon just forgot the alias to the `count(*)`.

Answer (score 0):

Hoping, i understood your problem correctly. Please try below query

```
select Vacancy.ID, VacancyID, count(*) as NumberOfApplications from           VacancyApplication
left join Vacancy on Vacancy.ID=VacancyID
group by VacancyID, Vacancy.ID
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use count as a window function using the [`OVER`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189461.aspx) clause, thus eliminating he need for group by:

```
SELECT v.ID,
       v.Active,
       v.StartDate,
       v.JobID,
       v.JobTypeID,
       COUNT(va.ID) OVER(PARTITION BY v.ID) HoursPerWeek
FROM Vacancy v
LEFT JOIN vacancyapplication va ON(v.ID = va.VacancyID)
```

Comment: might need partition by v.ID

Comment: @Paparazzi perhaps you are correct. Had the OP posted the question with sample data as DDL+DML I would bother testing my answer....

Comment: MSSM Studio isn't liking the syntax of 'va.*', do you have any idea why?

Comment: try `va.VacancyID` instead.